# Sonar scanner error: Unable to parse file

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have implemented ESlint Plugin in Sonarqube 5.6.6 for performing Sonar anlysis of a Javascript project. 
I am executing the following tasks:

1. Checking out the code from repository
2. Running `sonar-scanner` on the checked out code.

Although the task is getting executed successfully, but I am getting an error while executing the task. the logs for the error part is as follows:

```
 19:57:54.069 ERROR: Unable to parse file: /ebs/deployment/codebases/test-design/sonar/lib/atomic/List/LI/index.js
 19:57:54.071 ERROR: Parse error at line 14 column 40:

4: 
5: import React from 'react';
6: import classnames from 'classnames';
7: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
8: import styles from './LI.css';
9: 
10: 
11: // eslint-disable-next-line
12: console.log(styles.length);
13: 
14: const LI = ({ ...props, children, data = {}, titleKey = '', className = {}, styleNames, style, onClick, onMouseOver, onMouseOut }) => (
                                       ^
15:   <li
16:     {...props}
17:     className={classnames(className)}
18:     style={style}
19:     data={data}
20:     styleName={`li ${styleNames}`}
21:   >
22:     <button
23:       styleName="buttonsStyles"
24:       onClick={event => onClick(event, data)}

19:57:54.574 ERROR: Unable to parse file: /ebs/deployment/codebases/test-design/sonar/lib/atomic/Tabs/index.js
19:57:54.576 ERROR: Parse error at line 46 column 22:

36:         className={className}
37:         onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
38:         onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
39:         onClick={onClick}
40:       />)
41:     ))}
42:   </UL>);
43: 
44: const BorderedTab = ({
45:   ...props,
46:   liActiveStyleNames = '',
                     ^ 
47:   liStyleNames = '',
48:   ulStyleNames = '',
49: }) => (<TabComponent
50:   {...props}
51: 
52:   liStyleNames={`borderedTab ${liStyleNames || ''}`}
53:   liActiveStyleNames={`borderedTabAcive ${liActiveStyleNames || ''}`}
54:   ulStyleNames={`borderedTab ${ulStyleNames || ''}`}
55: />);
56:
```

Although the job ran successfully, but I am not sure whether the analysis is correct or not.
The `sonar-scanner` command is as follows:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.projectVersion=v1 -Dsonar.projectKey=test-design -Dsonar.projectName=test-DesigneSystem -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 '-Dsonar.exclusions=**/font/**' -X
```

The profiles which we are using: csslint, eslint

Can anybody tell me what may be the issue.

Comment: You could temporarily exclude index.js to check the results of the rest of the code. Then you can concentrate your effort on that file. Look if it is possible to temporarily exclude or write the problematic code section in another way.